# Switchgear dielectric testing and impulse polarity

Tags: electrical, testing

What is difference between negative and positive polarity impulse test? Why Negative only done for internal dielectric strength and positive polarity impulse only for external dielectric strength? Impulse voltage test of gas insulated switch gears??